# What is the error in the following OCaml Snippet?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Code:
`let ab = let a = 'a' in let b = 'B' in (Char.lowercase b) in a :: [b];;`

I am learning the `let` keyword. I want the expression to evaluate to the list of characters `['a', 'b']` but instead I keep getting the error

`Error: Unbound value a`

I don't know why this is happening. As far as I understand, I can keep using `let` inside `let` to create new bindings and I have used `let` to bind `a` to `'a'` in the beginning itself and hence it should have a valid value in the inner scope as well right?

I know that I can simply do `b = 'b'` instead of `b = 'B' in (Char.lowercase b)` but I am experimenting with what I can do and what I cannot do and to me this should also work.

Comment: `a :: [b]` can be simply written `[a; b]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have too many `in` keywords. The topmost `let` shouldn't have a corresponding `in`.

```
let ab =
  let a = 'a' in
    let b = 'B' in
      (Char.lowercase b) in
        a :: [b];;
```

Re-write it like this:

```
let ab =
  let a = 'a' in
    let b = 'B' in
      a :: [Char.lowercase b];;
```

In fact, since the `let b` expression doesn't refer to `a`, you can write it like this:

```
let ab =
  let a = 'a'
  and b = 'B' in
    a :: [Char.lowercase b];;
```

Comment: That works but I am not sure if I understand why writing the way I did caused `a` to become unbounded.

Comment: I think the error was misleading. The mistake was `in (Char.lowercase b) in`. It's almost like the second `in` brought you to the top-level scope (where `a` was no longer defined.)

Comment: If I understand correctly, are our bindings valid only till the expression `(Char.lowercase b)` and then we lose all our bindings? If so, then why didn't the compiler throw the error that `b` is also unbounded?

Comment: The syntax of ML is such that's it's hard to recover from compilation errors. In C/C++/Java, you can find the next semicolon and then try to continue compiling (to find further errors.) OCaml seems to stop after the first error since it's hard to re-sync with any code following the error. If you replace `a :: [b]` in your original example with `'0' :: [b]`, it'll complain about `b`.

Comment: And, yes, `let` bindings are local to the scope that they're defined. Top-level `let` bindings are available to the module. Nested `let` binding are only available until the end of the definition.

Comment: Thanks, that clarified a lot!

Comment: A more precise distinction is: the `let` keyword is used for two purposes (it is overloaded). Grammatically, `let p = e in e'` is an expression, and the bindings introduced by `p` are available in `e'` (not "until the end of the definition"). `let p = e` is a structure item (i.e. at the "module level"). It's a totally separate construct, but has a resemblance. The bindings introduced by `p` in this case are available in subsequent structure items. The use of `let` for both can be seen as unfortunate. SML, for instance, does not overload `let` in this way.

Comment: @antron But then this brings up my doubt again, if `let p = e in e'` provides the binding of `p` in `e'` then my code should provide a valid binding for `a` right?

Comment: If you parenthesize your expression, you get `let ab = (let a = 'a' in (let b = 'B' in (Char.lowercase b))) in (a :: [b])`. That means you are binding `ab` in `a::[b]`. The `a` and `b` are only visible inside the expression whose result gets bound to `ab`. BTW, nice name :) EDIT: in other words, `ab` got bound to the lowercase `"b"`, and the names `a` and `b` were visible only while you were computing that lowercase `"b"`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on discussion in comments, I would also suggest, if you want an expression:

```
let ab =
  let a = 'a' in
  let b = 'B' in
  a::[Char.lowercase b]
in
(* The rest of your code. *)
```

The problem is that your expression was this:

```
let ab =
  let a = 'a' in
  let b = 'B' in
  Char.lowercase b   (* Result: ab gets bound to 'b'. *)
in
a :: [b]             (* a and b aren't visible out here! *)
```

I also recommend indenting in a style similar to this one, to help you see such things clearly. OCaml programmers usually break lines before let. If you have `let p = e in e'` and `e` or `e'` don't fit on one line, indent the `e`, but not the `e'`. That way, you can quickly see which further expressions the bindings of `p` are visible in, and see that any bindings made in `e` are not visible in `e'`.

Comment: That explains everything! Thanks a lot!!